# How do black hole researchers (safely) research black holes?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information

Wouldn't they just fall in and die, thus ending their scientific careers?

Just wondering,
Hank

Comment: There are many ways to study a thing without being right next to it.

Comment: There are no black hole researchers who went near a black hole. Black holes are thousands of light years farther than us. They take the gamma emission and sudden bursts of energy to predict a black hole. Also Hawking radiation.

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes, this is a legitimate question about physics from somebody who does not know the answer and wonders how or why. If this question cannot be answered at the level of the question(er) then the rules of this forum are not properly defined to accommodate beginners. And the three posts given below show that it is possible to answer this question appropriately at a beginner's level.

Comment: @hyportnex Yes, thanks to Adrian Howard, JEB and Martin Vesley for their excellent answers below, and to hyportnex for supporting good answers.

Answer (score 5):

The nearest known black hole, designation HR6819, is approximately 1,120 light years away. At this time we have no way to actually send a living scientist that far. Data concerning black holes mainly comes from radio telescope arrays. The Event Horizon Telescope Collaboration released the first image of a black hole, Messier 87, in April 2019. See image at; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_Telescope#/media/File:Black_hole_-_Messier_87_crop_max_res.jpg

Comment: 1,120 light years, that's quite a long haul - how do they know it's there?

Comment: HR 6819 contains a Be star and a B type giant star. The B giant is in an approximate 40 day orbit but it does not orbit the Be star, so there is a third non emitting body it orbits. Orbital parameters suggest the third body is massive enough that it must be a black hole.

Answer (score 2):

The equations of general relativity (EFE) were published in 1915, and were complicated enough that Einstein did not think a "nice" solution would be possible.

A year later, Karl Schwarzschild published a nice solution, and black hole research had begun. Without going into a comprehensive history, it took a long time to realized what the solution was (a black hole), and that it could actually exist in nature. So much of the research was done safely in the ivory towers of academia, save for Schwarzschild himself, who did perhaps the most dangerous research, as he found his solution while serving on the Russian From in World War I.

By the 1950, quasars were discovered and observational research on black holes started (again, safely), although it took some time before people were understood that quasars were power by black holes. Observation work continues to this day, with LIGO and Sagittarius A* receiving the 2017 and 2020 Nobel prizes in physics, respectively.

The third area of active research involves computers, with the first attempt at solving the EFE occurring in 1964. The field, now called Numerical Relativity, has made huge advances, particularly because of LIGO's need to understand the gravitational radiation emitted by black hole mergers.

As far as physically observing a black hole, LIGO comes the closest, as it probes the space-time near event horizons by detecting the gravitational radiation emitted during black hole mergers and the subsequent ring down of the final black hole.

As black holes are made *from* space-time, and the gravitational waves detected here on Earth are waves *in* space-time, one could say they are part of the black hole system. If that is too much, then perhaps accept that the black hole is reaching out an touching us, literally, by stretching and squishing our length by about one 20 millionth the diameter of a proton, and it does this from a safe 1 billion light year distance.

Answer (score 2):

Of course black holes are not studied directly by orbiting around them. They are too far to do so (several tens or hundreds light years).

However, we can detect and study them indirectly. As a black hole has a mass, it exerts gravitational force on other objects. This force changes motion of these object which we can detect. Also when a black hole "consume" a matter, electromagnetic radiation is produced and we can detect it. The most recent method of black hole research involves detection of gravitational waves.